# React setState for Font Color with array index

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Im having difficulties understanding setState. im able to make the color change but all of the array items turns red with this code. Im new in react so please help me here

```
{class.map((c, index) => (
   <Link style={{color: this.state.fcolor}} key={index} onClick={(e) => { 
      this.handleChangeColor(index) }}>
      {c.classname}<i className="fa fa-check"> </i>
   </Link>
))}

handleChangeColor(event, index){
     this.setState({
        fcolor: "red"
     })
}
```

I want it specifically using index but when i add the index

fcolor[index]:'red' is runs tru an error that needs an ','

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because all your link may share the same state. A good pattern to show an active link, would be to store an active ID to specify wich link should show a red color.

You can inspire you from this Tab component, found at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-tabs-component

```
class Tab extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    activeTab: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  onClick = () => {
    const { label, onClick } = this.props;
    onClick(label);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      onClick,
      props: {
        activeTab,
        label,
      },
    } = this;

    let className = 'tab-list-item';

    if (activeTab === label) {
      className += ' tab-list-active';
    }

    return (
      <li
        className={className}
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        {label}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default Tab;
```